# How to get back to an active minibuffer prompt in emacs without the mouse

Tags: emacs, focus, mouseless, minibuffer

In emacs, sometimes I will be in the middle of finding a file or switching buffers or doing something in the minibuffer, and I will click somewhere else for some reason. When I go back, the only way to make the minibuffer prompt active again is to click inside the minibuffer, which is annoying because it is a thin area. Is there any way to switch back to an active minibuffer prompt without using the mouse?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This will do what you want.  Bind to the key of your choice:

```
(defun switch-to-minibuffer-window ()
  "switch to minibuffer window (if active)"
  (interactive)
  (when (active-minibuffer-window)
    (select-frame-set-input-focus (window-frame (active-minibuffer-window)))
    (select-window (active-minibuffer-window))))
(global-set-key (kbd "<f7>") 'switch-to-minibuffer-window)
```

Comment: If you have multiple frames then you need to add `(select-frame-set-input-focus (window-frame (active-minibuffer-window)))` before the `select-window`.

Comment: @dshepherd I can confirm that after inserting your Elisp line, the enriched function is working well with only one frame as well. Thanks.

Comment: @dshepherd Thanks, have updated code appropriately.

Answer (score 25):

```
C-x o
```

*Repeat as necessary.*

C-x o runs the command other-window, which is an interactive built-in
function in `C source code'.

If you do not want to cycle through windows, you can add a function in your init file and bind it to a key.  Something like this might work:

```
(defun select-minibuffer ()
 "Make the active minibuffer the selected window."
 (interactive)
 (when (active-minibuffer-window)
   (select-window (active-minibuffer-window))))
```

Comment: Why would you want to include `RET` like that? It would automatically accept whatever was in the minibuffer (assuming a single `C-x o` switched to the minibuffer). Generally, one may need to use `C-x o` multiple times if there are (in Emacs parlance) multiple windows open in the frame (in normal GUI terms: multiple panes in the window).

Comment: You're right.  My bad.

Comment: Is there any way to get directly to the minibuffer without potentially cycling through all windows? Should I just write a loop that does `other-window` until current window is minibuffer?

Answer (score 6):

Another option is using [`switch-window`](http://github.com/dimitri/switch-window)

I find it to be a really useful package: it allows you to quickly move to any Emacs window, visually (and I do use a lot of open windows in Emacs).

But I just find out it also allows you to move to the minibuffer, if it is active:

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: A related package is [`swap-buffers`](https://github.com/ekazakov/swap-buffers/blob/master/swap-buffers.el) which uses the same method for swapping the current buffer with that in another window.

Answer (score 0):

```
;; faster switching between windows in the same frame
(windmove-default-keybindings)
```

Adding two above lines of code to .emacs.el will enable simple and efficient moving, not just to minibuffer, but also navigating all other windows on  Emacs frame using [**Shift-Arrow**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WindMove).